# Como identificar arquivos em um mesmo padrão de nome, que estejam em um determinado diretório, usando Python?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

Preciso fazer com que o **Python** identifique os arquivos que preciso, e se for um deles, abra para tratamento:

1) Todos os arquivos estão no mesmo diretório, exemplo: *(r'C:\Users\Eu\Desktop\Teste\Teste de Arquivo\nome_123456_10102010_11_20.xls')*
2) Todos no mesmo formato (exemplo acima);
3) O nome é com cinco caracteres;
4) os símbolos de underline separam os campos;
5) Os demais campos são todos numéricos;
6) A extensão é sempre .xls

Tentei usando a biblioteca **RE** e a biblioteca **OS**, usando o comando **os.path.exists** que deveria retornar True se encontrasse o arquivo através dos caracteres curinga, mas só retornava False.

Será que biblioteca RE não funciona com diretórios?
Como seria possível fazer isso com Python?

Comment: "nome é com cinco caracteres", mas no seu exemplo "nome" só possui 4. Pesquise sobre `pathlib.Path.glob`.

Comment: 'nome' foi apenas para exemplificar, ali seria substituído por 5 caracteres/letras. Obrigado pela sugestão

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer com o pathlib.

Este código retorna uma lista chamada `path` de todos os arquivos no local especificado.

Dentro do `for` você pode testar se o `nome_arquivo` existe.

Veja mais detalhes na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

```
import pathlib

path = list(pathlib.Path(".").glob("*"))

for nome_arquivo in path:

    print(nome_arquivo)
```

Comment: Obrigado, estou agora fazendo testes com  esse pathlib, e tentando juntar com algumas coisas da biblioteca RE para filtrar o padrão do arquivo (pois o nome deste é variável).